# Changing display mode resets scale to 100%

Tags: 18.04, unity, 20.04, multiple-monitors, scaling

I have not been able to find a proper answer online so I ask here:

My current display scaling is set to 200% and I'm working on two 4K displays.

Whenever I change the display mode with `[ctrl]+[p]` to *join* or *mirror*, the scaling value is reset to 100%.

- This is a relatively fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.
- I had exactly the same issue with Ubuntu 18.04.

Whenever I change the mode in `Settings -> Screen Display`, I experience that the *Scale* group-button goes to 100% whenever I switch mode.

I start with this:
[image: First]

Then I end up with this:

[image: End]

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing your scaling level at 200% via gsettings:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2
```